# PropertyGrid mult. controls select, null exception on property set?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, propertygrid, windows-forms-designer

I have a custom object, ComplexName, that I want to show in the propertygrid (in the VS designer, not at runtime).

It all seems to work correctly (with the ExpandableObjectConverter implemented), when I have just one control selected.  I can set any\all of the attributes the way I want them to (expanded or via the typeconverter).

When I select multiple controls though, the issue starts.

At first, When you selected multiple objects with the same property (with the same value), I wanted the text to show (similar to dock, for instance).  I fixed that by overriding equals.

The problem:

When I have multiple object selected, and I type in a new value for the object, one of two things will happen:

If all object currently have the same value: the new value is loaded properly.
if the values are not equal: a null pointer exception will be thrown.

Keep in mind this is only on the "typeconverter" line.  If i multi-select and change any objects in the expanded section, everything is fine.